# Junit method invocation fails due to spring injection

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, junit, dependency-injection

I have written Junit test class to test particular method. One of the variables being processed in this method is spring injected, by taking the value from properties file.

Below is my test method

```
@Test 
public void myTestMethod() {
  //invoking the method to be tested
  Assert.assertTrue(updateGroceries());
}
```

This is the class to be tested,

```
   public class ToBeTested {

   //Spring injected value
   String categories;

   public boolean updateGroceries() {
   List<String> categoryList = StringUtils.convertStringToList(categories);
   }
```

In the above class, categories variable is spring injected.
This is properties file content:

```
categories = Dals,Pulses,Dry Fruits,Edible Oil
```

Now while running my Junit method, execution is failing because dependency injection is failing.Since the code I want to test runs on tomcat. I want to test the code without running tomcat. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to run mockito you need to enable it over your test.
Using annotation `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` or execute at the beginning of your test `Mockito.initMocks()`.
Then your test should look like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
private YourTest{

   @InjectMocks
   ToBeTested toBeTested;

   @Mock
   ToBeTestedDependency dependency;

   @Before
   public void setUp(){
      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(toBeTested, "categories",
            "someCategory");
   }

   @Test
   public void shouldDoThisOrThat(){
      toBeTested.updateCategories();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately mockito doesn't support injecting `@Value`annotated field. You need to use `ReflectionTestUtils` or setup run your test with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` where you need to define your spring context with `PropertyPlaceholder` configuration to resolve property that you have as your `Value` key. There you can find reference to [documentation and example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html) of spring testing approach.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Mockito. When you use mockito framework, you can create mocks for spring injected values. You should read more on mockito [website](http://mockito.org/).